# Low frame rate in every game with capable enough hardware

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gaming, dell-inspiron, fps

**MSI Afterburner Monitoring**

1. Counter-Strike : Global Offensive: 
    [image: Counter-Strike : Global Offensive]
2. Sleeping Dogs: 
    [image: Sleeping Dogs]

**Facts and observations**

1. CPU and GPU not fully utilized.
2. FPS stays around 20 - 25 in every game.
3. Temperatures are normal.
4. All the drivers including Graphics, BIOS and Chipset are up to date.
5. Wiping the hard disk and re-installing the windows did not solved the problem.
6. I have finished many games till the end without any noticeable lags before.
7. I do not remember exactly when it started happening, I did not fixed this because I thought a hard reset will definitely fix it and I was just not ready to back up and do this to my 1 TB hard disk. Finally, after around 1.5 years I did it but it did not got fixed.
8. Laptop is on high performance mode both in Power settings and AMD Radeon settings.
9. All the games are being monitored on the lowest settings at 720p resolution. Earlier I could run them on Medium settings at 1080p resolution. I did not monitored framerate before becasue it was playing just fine.
10. The game files are the same as before. No updates.

**System Information**

- Dell Inspiron 15R N5521
- Intel Core i5-3337U Processor (3M Cache, up to 2.70 GHz)
- 4GB 1 DIMM (4GB x1) DDR3 1600MHz
- AMD Radeon HD 8730M with 2GB DDR3 VRAM
- Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: no, the CPU is a dual core CPU and the U stands for low power version for ultrabook which should have long battery life. Aslo the AMD GPU only has DDR3 and now GDDR5, so this GPU is also low/midrange hardware.

Comment: But the point is, all of this worked fine before. Even on high resolution and medium settings. Something has happened and I am asking for help to figure out what could have happened.

Comment: Further, although I did not measured FPS when everything was fine, the reviews of my laptop on notebookcheck show that I should be getting more than 150 FPS in CS : GO. Which I feel, was getting it before.

Comment: what have you changed that it is now slower? Have you installed a driver or Windows 10 update?

Comment: It started before updating to Windows 10. I have tried with stock drivers as well, which came up installed with the laptop.

Comment: Can you check the `power profile` that you have windows set to? If you happend to have changed it to `balanced`, or `battery saver`, it will drastically cut back on performance, especially when gaming. When these games are running, open task manager - are any of your resources pegged?

Comment: It was High Performance both in Power Settings and AMD Radeon settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved. The problem was with the charger, it was not giving the rated output.

## **Learning**

> If drivers and a hard reset do not fix the problem, temperatures are
>   normal, clock speed is not limited but *utilization is less*, power
>   supply could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for writing a good question and answering itt, welcome to the network! You could improve your answer further by listing other possible causes such as blocked vents, dust build up, or anti virus software.

Comment: Thanks Peter! I look forward to be a reputed programmer like you. :)
Thanks for suggesting ways to improve my answer but those problems are not valid in this case since blocked vents or dust build up would eventually raise the temperatures and cause throttling which, in my case were normal and any software problem like anti-virus would get fixed on a hard reset.

Comment: nice to see that you fixed it.

Comment: I'm so happy :D